# Can ping ec2 server (ubuntu/apache) but don't get response from http request

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, http

Background:

- OS: ubuntu
- Web Server: apache2

What works:

- I can ping the server's elastic IP (and receive a response)
- I can ssh into the server

What doesn't work:

- I cannot get any sort of http response from the server

Expected Behavior:

- When I go to http://ec2-XXX-XX-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com/, it will serve my page, or at least give me a 404 that I can debug

Actual Behavior:

- When I go to http://ec2-XXX-XX-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com/, it says "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to ec2-XXX-XX-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com". It doesn't even give me a 404.

Rant:

Clearly the server is there because I can ssh in to that exact address and I can ping that exact IP and get a response. But when I go that exact address in my web browser it's as if it never makes it to the server. Or it's as if Amazon isn't letting http requests through, but in my security group I am clearly specifying that http requests from all sources are allowed through. Apache is definitely running, my document root is definitely set up properly, and my error and access logs don't give me anything.

Is there any sort of log in between Amazon and the server, or in between requests making it to the server and being received by Apache that would specify why it's returning "not found" rather than a 404. Can I make my Apache logs more verbose?

Thanks in advance! I've spent hours on this....

Comment: Did you check DNS? Did you try to use `nslookup ec2-XX-XX...` or `dig` or any name resolution tool? Did you get the same IP address?

Comment: nslookup ec2-XXX-XX-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com will return the ip address so it seems that is working. I can also do nslookup sub.mydomain.com and it returns the same ip address.

Comment: If you try `telnet your_ip 80`, what do you get?

Comment: Is port 80 open in your firewall rules?

Comment: So if I do telnet XXX-XX-XXX-XXX 80, it says "telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused". However, my security group in Amazon's ec2 settings clearly says to allowed traffic through on 80. Might be worth mentioning that I'm trying this from cygwin, but  I'm guessing it should be the same. Also, when I run "netstat -net" on the server (ssh'd in) I get the following line: "tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting connection refused from `telnet` output, this means you are connecting to a closed port on your server.

You have a line in `netstat -lnp` that reads:

```
tcp    0      0 0.0.0.0:80         0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN      1662/apache2
```

If your apache is listening on different port, you need to specify that port in the URL like: `http://ec2-XXX...com:8080/` if the port is 8080.

Comment: My apache files were set to Listen 8080 instead of Listen 80...